# How to auto display image from Google Drive hosted?

Tags: javascript, blogger

I have an id "content", it contains many Google Drive URLs of images. So, I have math all URLs and replace it with clickable link.

But I can not display it likes a nother images.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function replace_content(content)
   {
   var exp_match =  /(\b(https?|):\/\/drive\.google\.com\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;;
   var element_content=content.replace(exp_match, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
   return element_content;
   }

   var content = $('#content').html();
   $('#content').html(replace_content(content));
```

I can not cut image id from each URL found. Who can help me?

I hope my question will be answered. Auto display all image hosted in Google Drive in the id "content"